# MUI V5 DateTimePicker not displaying the expected Yup validation error message

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I am building a form with Yup, React Hook Form and, MUI V5.  I am using a `DateTimePicker` from MUI V5 but it is not displaying Yup's error messages as expected.
Ideally, the errors should display as follow:

1. Invalid format message: Invalid date format. (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am or
   pm)
2. Required field's message: The field cannot be left blank.
3. Additionally, when there is a validation error or when the field
   loses its focus it does not turn red.

So, if the field is empty and I press the submit button, the invalid format message is displayed.

here is the schemas code:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .required("Please enter your name. The field cannot be left blank."),
  date: yup
    .date()
    .transform(parseDateString)
    .typeError("Invalid date format. (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am or pm)")
    .nullable()
    .required("Please enter a valid date. The field cannot be left blank.")
});
```

I have tried moving `nullable()` to every different position and the result still the same.
I have commented `nullable()` and `typeError` and I get the default error from date (date must be a `date` type, but the final value was: `Invalid Date`.)

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-rhf-and-yup-template-efykt?file=/src/schema.js)

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? If yes, could you post your solution here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Invalid Date` error comes from the `date-fns` parser function that is in the `parseDateString` function called in the Yup transform method.

Yup transform method is used to transform incoming date from the input field, in this case it's MUI's DateTimePicker.

That being sad it has nothing to do with this error and the problem is in the `DatePicker` component. Make note of the `TextField` and `{...params}` destructuring. Since the error prop was before we destructure params it was overwritten.

[Here is a working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-rhf-and-yup-template-forked-n3qiw6?file=/src/DatePicker.js:697-1189)

```
const CalPicker = ({ helperText, name, label, control, required, error }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  return (
    <Stack sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
        <Controller
          name={name}
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <DateTimePicker
              {...field}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  required={required}
                  {...params}
                  helperText={helperText}
                  error={error}
                />
              )}
              label={label}
              value={value}
              onChange={(newValue) => {
                field.onChange(newValue);
                setValue(newValue);
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add under LocalizationProvider:

```
{error ? <div className="error">{error}</div> : null}
```